# Creating a smimple neural network to predict and generate music

Tags: neural-network, julia, flux.jl

I am currently trying to implement a neural network which will generate music based upon training it is given. I am writing in Julia, using the Flux package, however I'm finding the documentation a bit difficult to grasp (I understand the logic behind nn, however, I am still getting confused between what the different functions do).

I have started by setting up some training data to feed into the model:

```
# trainingData = an 2D array of note pitches and rhythms.
# sortedData = the same as traingData but with duplicates removed.
# The function iterates through the training data and pushes an index value (its position in 
# the sortedData array) to a new array, labels.

function labelData(trainingData, sortedData)
  labels = []
  # For each note, create a numerical label based on index of the note in the sorted data.
  for note in trainingData
    push!(labels, findfirst(isequal(note), sortedData))
  end
  return labels
end
```

The idea would be to feed the value at index 1 of labels into the model and tell it the expected output is the value at index 2. Then give it index 2 and say the expected output is index 3, and so forth. These values then act as a map which we can use to get the original pitch and rhythm.

Am I right in saying the model would then be able to generate some music based on predictions?

Would someone be able to give me a head start on how I would create a model to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: It looks like a too broad question for SO  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    Perhaps you could provide a simplified  MWE and start from then?

Comment: This is not julia specific, but look up Markov chain for music generation.  That is how what you are planning has been done in the past.

Comment: Thanks Bill, that's actually really helpful!